# Android Receive SMS and Play a Music Service

Tags: android, service, sms, media-player

I am new to android programming and I am having a problem with getting a SMS received service to play an audio file relating to the text message coming in.  I have a working sample that kind of works but I am not able to stop the music file from playing nor choose another file to play with out over lapping audio.  So I it seems like I need to have the SMS received service call a mediaplayer service but don't know how.  Also I would need to have the music stop with an unmatched text message.  Any help would be greatfull.  This is what I have that works with out the audio service.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;


public class SMSreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 MediaPlayer mp1;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent)
{
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        

    //mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.jingle);

    if(null != bundle)
    {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

        SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
        {
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

            if(messages[i].getDisplayMessageBody().equals("a"))
            {
                //Play alarm sound 
                mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.a);
                mp1.setLooping(true); // Set looping
                mp1.start();
            } //---------------------------------------------------
            if(messages[i].getDisplayMessageBody().equals("b"))
            {
                //Play alarm sound 
                mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.b);
                mp1.setLooping(true); // Set looping
                mp1.start();
            } //---------------------------------------------------

            if(messages[i].getDisplayMessageBody().equals("c"))
            {
                //Play alarm sound 
                mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.c);
                mp1.setLooping(true); // Set looping
                mp1.start();
            } //---------------------------------------------------

            if(messages[i].getDisplayMessageBody().equals("d"))
            {
                //Play alarm sound 
                mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.d);
                mp1.setLooping(true); // Set looping
                mp1.start();

            }  //---------------------------------------------------


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using a thread.I Removed the `mp1.setLooping(true);` part and used this

`mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.calmpiano);`

```
        mp1.start();


        Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    while(true && (waited < 5000)) {
                        sleep(100);
                        if(true) {
                            waited += 100;
                        }
                    }
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    // do nothing
                } finally {
                   // finish();
                    //startActivity(new Intent("com.talktome.android.MyOne.MyOneActivity"));
                    stop();
                }
            }
        };
        splashTread.start();
}

        `
```

Answer (score 0):

Register BroadcastReceiver Class in your Project listen the incoming sms tutorial and code Below link 
http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/ 
after Broadcast Receiver Class listen receive sms to Start the media player activity